# How JModelica(v2.14) enable directional derivatives?

Tags: modelica, simulate, jmodelica

I'm using PyFMI.master to do co-simulation and the FMUs are compiled by JModelica.

However, PyFMI.master said that "UserWarning: The model, room_interface_3, does not support directional derivatives which is necessary in-case of an algebraic loop. The simulation might become unstable..."

It is indeed unstable because my co-simulation crashed with an absurd situation(like temperature blew the min limit).

So, are there any solutions to this problem?
Thanks in advance!